# Where does Windows 7 get its Locale Data?

Tags: windows, unicode, localization, internationalization

What data drives Windows 7 locale's (for dates, times, etc.)? I know in most Linux systems (and I believe OS X), they use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) which in turn uses the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) for it's data.

[1](http://site.icu-project.org/) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They pay linguists and other experts to produce locale data for them. They do not rely on any external source like CLDR.

Comment: Being a large company with lots of money, Microsoft doesn't like to provide any openings for possible lawsuits. They do everything in-house as much as possible.

Comment: Not a total surprise but I wanted to know. Thanks!